# How can I override the Calendar module's theme functions?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to override [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module's theme functions. Specifically, I'm trying to override `template_preprocess_calendar_month()` and `template_preprocess_calendar_mini()`.

The override seems to work, but the problem is that the variables are processed/modified by `template_preprocess_calendar_month()` and `template_preprocess_calendar_mini()` before they reach the functions I implemented.

I need access to some of the theme variables before they are processed. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom module and define your own copies of these preprocess functions.

For this example we'll call your module `mysite`.

In your mysite.module file you would define:

```
mysite_preprocess_calendar_mini(&$variables)
mysite_preprocess_calendar_month(&$variables)
```

And then modify the contents of the variables in these functions as needed. Copying the existing preprocess functions might be a good place to start if you're not sure what you want to modify.

Check out [the preprocess documentation](http://drupal.org/node/223430) for some more information about how this system works.

Comment: `template_preprocess_calendar_mini()` is always executed before any implementation of `hook_preprocess_calendar_mini()`; there isn't the need to copy the code of `template_preprocess_calendar_mini()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, since `template_preprocess_calendar_month()` is executed before `mytheme_preprocess_calendar_month()`, assuming that *mytheme* is the machine name of the theme you implemented.

The order of execution of those functions is described in the documentation for [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7.x), which shows the following order, where *MODULE* is the machine name of any enabled module, *ENGINE* is the machine name of the theme engine used, and *THEME* is the machine name of the theme used to render the page.

- `template_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`
- `template_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)`
- `MODULE_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`
- `MODULE_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)`
- `ENGINE_engine_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`
- `ENGINE_engine_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)`
- `THEME_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`
- `THEME_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)`

Answer (score 0):

It may help to play with the modules weight (execution order). Switching the execution order of the custom module and the calendar module might help.

The order may be changed at the system table (e.g. `update system set weight = -10 where name='mymodule'`) , or via the [modules_weight](http://drupal.org/project/modules_weight) module.